# SharePoint 2010 - How to enable New action to add a user into a group with STS user?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2010

I'm a newbie with SP2010. I have a problem with menu toolbar in Group Permision

I has set up STS for user (Claim-based) to login to my website. I created a group called Super User (which has Full Control permission) programmatically and granted this group a user. Then using this user login to Website. Now when I go to Permission page and choose a group to view. In that group page, I realize that the New action menu does not exist. In order to add new user to the group, I have to go to Site Actions/Site Permissions and use Ribbon menu to add users to group. But my group Super User does not appear in Grant Permission dropdown list of the Grant Permission popup modal.

However if I login via Windows Authentication (domain account), I can see the New action menu and can add new user directly in this page.

In addition, if I view a predefined Group of SharePoint such as Owner, Member, Visitor, Designers... I can see the New action when login by STS User.

How can I enable the New action menu when I login with STS user?